# Element wise averages across three pandas dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I created 3 Pandas data frames each containing the same 6 columns, but from different sources:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
            #excluding the edges b/c nothing interesting happens there
        "z-coordinate (nm)": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[1]["water"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,0], 
        "water": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[1]["water"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "acyl chains": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[1]["acyl"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "headgroups": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[1]["head"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "ester": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[1]["ester"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "protein": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[1]["proa"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1]
        })

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "z-coordinate (nm)": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[2]["water"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,0], 
        "water": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[2]["water"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "acyl chains": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[2]["acyl"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "headgroups": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[2]["head"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "ester": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[2]["ester"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "protein": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[2]["proa"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1]
        })

df_3 = pd.DataFrame({
        "z-coordinate (nm)": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[3]["water"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,0], 
        "water": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[3]["water"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "acyl chains": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[3]["acyl"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "headgroups": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[3]["head"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "ester": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[3]["ester"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1],
        "protein": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[3]["proa"])._auxdata_values[8:42:1,1]
        })
```

I want to create a single dataframe that uses the averages of each element from these three (i.e. same size/shape, but average of each entry). I know pandas has built in modules for averaging columns and rows, but I couldn't find anything on element-wise averaging. Is there anyway to do this with pandas or would I have to figure out an alternative method?

Comment: Is it just `(df_1+df_2+df_3)/3`?

Comment: Yes. That worked. Thank you.